# Listview not Scroll fully

Tags: android, listview

I am using a list view in linear layout but it not scrolled fully at the list item. I added my screenshot of genymotion.Please help i using different different lisview classes but non  of them works also uses nested scrollview but none of them working.

Code.xml

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textdescriptiontitle"
            android:text="  TRANSACTION "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffa500"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Movie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Movie" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subscription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Subscription" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_msg_on_transaction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="   Please Logged In To See Your Transaction" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of my list view]

Comment: Why do you have so much empty linear layouts?

Comment: u r rightt @jonathanrz !!! itz because of the empty layouts !!! thnxxxx